# デスクトップ版Chrome（for iOS）からスマホサイト表示ができない

Tags: google-chrome

Chromeでスマホ表示が過去にできていたのですが，急にf12でスマホ表示を選択してリフレッシュしても表示されなくなりました．
ディベロッパーツール→設定→デバイスで一度「Laptop with HiDPI screen」を選択したことはありますが，設定を戻しても使えないです

PCの情報は以下です
Mac OS High Sierra
バージョン10.13.6（17G7024）
MacBookPro

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/70440771?hl=ja

Comment: mac でデスクトップ版なのに "for iOS" というのは説明が矛盾しているように思います。

Answer (score 0):

外しているかもしれませんが、私もよくやるので一応書いておきます。

Shift + コマンドキー + M

で切り替わりませんか？アイコンでは下図の左から二番目の（矢印で示した）ものが相当します。
これがスマホ表示と通常画面と切り替えになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]